# Здравствуйте, вопрос о списке, добавления в список

Tags: python, list

Не удаётся сделать так, чтобы если slovo1 было хотя бы в виде сочетания букв в slovarj1, то выводилось бы "Такое слово есть", а иначе stroka добавлялась бы с словарь

```py
slovarj1 = list()
slovarj2 = list()
while (True):
    stroka=input("Введите текст")
#1. Добавление в словарь
    if ":" in stroka and stroka.count(":")==1:
        dt=stroka.find(":")
        slovo1=stroka[0:dt]]
        slovo2=stroka[dt+1:len(stroka)+1]
        element=(slovo2+":"+slovo1)
        probely=stroka[dt-1:dt+2]
        probely=probely.strip()
        for x in slovarj1:
            if  slovo1in x:
                print ("такое слово есть")
            else:
                slovarj1.append(stroka)
                slovarj2.append(element)
                print ("слово добавлено")
                slovarj1.sort()
                slovarj2.sort()
```

---

В первой строке стоит также slovarj1=list()

синтаксические ошибки после отправления вопроса исправил, теперь просто возвращает None

Comment: Опишите задачу нормально, с примером

Comment: `if  slovo1in x:` пробела перед in не хватает. Если синтаксические ошибки исправили, добавьте актуальный код в вопрос. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit] под ним.